MPI_Cart_Create, MPI_Cart_coords and MPI_Cart_shift
I want to make a virtual topology of cpus using MPI_Cart_create
eg. total 12 cpus are decomposed into 232 in z (orthogonal to the screen), y (vertical), and x (horizontal) directions.
`int nprocxyz[3]={2,3,2};
int periods[3]{0,0,0};
int reorganisation{0};
MPI_Cart_create(comm, 3, nprocxyz, periods, reorganisation, &comm3d);
MPI_Cart_coords(comm3d, me, 3 , &coords[0]);`
From this, I got correct coords for each cpu, e.g, for cpu 10, the coordinate
is (1,2,0), (i.e., z=1, y=2, and x=0)
Now, I call MPI_Cart_shift to get neighbouring cpus for each cpu, i.e.,
MPI_Cart_shift(comm3d, 0, 1, &neighbors[0], &neighbors[1]);     //x-direction MPI_Cart_shift(comm3d, 1, 1, &neighbors[2], &neighbors[3]);     //y-direction  MPI_Cart_shift(comm3d, 2, 1, &neighbors[4], &neighbors[5]);     //z-direction
But, I got the wrong neighbors, e.g. for cpu 10, I got
4 -2 8 -2 -2 11
Instead of
-2 11 8 12 -2 2
Thanks for help
I feel I have wrong call to MPI_Cart_shift in combination with MPI_Cart_create, but could not figure out what is the cause leading to unmatching cpu neighbors.

please edit your question and add a [mcve]

"12 cpus are decomposed into 232" Says who? MPI_Dims_create find the largest factor first, so it would decompose 322.

Hi, thank you all.  I am using MPI_Cart_create, where I have provided a given vector that specifies the dimension of cpus by int nprocxyz[3]={2,3,2},  then I call MPI_Cart_create(comm, 3, nprocxyz, periods, reorganisation, &comm3d). which actually produces the dimension 232.
